# Why gmail account does not receive email from custom email account?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I use `nodemailer` to send `noreply` emails with activation codes to customers. Firstly, for testing I used my own gmail account to send emails with 2fa codes. Everything worked fine. After I purchased a domain and set up a custom email account as `noreply@mydomain.org`, I gave this address to nodemailer (I set everything up correctly as shown in the cpanel  instructions). Problem is, my `gmail account` doesn't receive emails sent from `nodemailer` if I use my custom email. I made an experiment. I set up another custom account `office@mydomain.org` and tried to send mails to it using `nodemailer` using the `noreply@mydomain.org` account. Everything works! But why wouldn't GMAIL receive them?